# $\Omega$ open and $K$ compact $\Rightarrow B_\varepsilon(0)+K\subset\Omega$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded set and $K\subset\Omega$ compact.

I'm trying to prove that for $\varepsilon$ small enough we have $(B_\varepsilon(0)+K)\subset\Omega$.

Consider the case $N=1$, $\Omega=(a,b)$ and $K=[c,d]$. If we take $\varepsilon<\min\{b-d,c-a\}$ then

$$\begin{align*}x\in(B_\varepsilon(0)+K)&\Rightarrow x=y+z\text{ with }y\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\text{ and }z\in[c,d]\\
&\Rightarrow-\varepsilon+c < x<\varepsilon+d\\
&\Rightarrow a < x<b\\
&\Rightarrow x\in \Omega
\end{align*}$$
so that the inclusion holds.

How to deal with the general case?

Comment: Consider the function $\operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\Omega)$. That is continuous. And positive on $\Omega$, in particular on $K$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you give more details? I think it's not exactly what you have suggested, but if we take $\varepsilon<\text{dist}(\partial\Omega,\partial K)$ then  
$x\in(B_\varepsilon(0)+K)\Rightarrow x=y+z\text{ with }y\in B_\varepsilon(0)\text{ and }z\in K$  
$\Rightarrow \text{dist}(x,\partial K)\leq\|y\|+d(z,\partial K)$  
$\Rightarrow \text{dist}(x,\partial K)\leq\varepsilon+0$  
$\Rightarrow \text{dist}(x,\partial K)\leq \text{dist}(\partial\Omega,\partial K)$.  
From this, is it possible to conclude that $x\in\Omega$?

Comment: It's much easier if you use $\operatorname{dist}(K,\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\Omega)$. Then you have it directly. But since $\operatorname{dist}(K,\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\Omega) = \operatorname{dist}(\partial K,\partial\Omega)$, it works too. If you have $x = y+z$ with $\lVert y\rVert < \varepsilon$ and $z\in K$, then either $x\in K$ and you're set, or you can deduce that the line segment connecting $z$ and $x$ must intersect $\partial K$. Since its length is $<\varepsilon$, that line segment cannot intersect $\partial \Omega$ too.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x \in K \subseteq \Omega$, there is an open ball $B(x, r_x)$ around $x$, and contained in $\Omega$. But then $$\{B(x, r_x) : x \in X\}$$

forms an open cover of $K$, so....

Comment: Should we take $\varepsilon < \min\{r_i;\;1\leq i\leq n\}$ where $\{B(x_i,r_i):1\leq i\leq n\}$ is a finite subcover of $K$?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, that works.

Comment: Take $\varepsilon<\min\{r_i;\;1\leq i\leq n\}$. Hence,  
$x\in(B_\varepsilon(0)+K)\Rightarrow x=y+z\text{ with }y\in B_\varepsilon(0)\text{ and }z\in K$  
$\Rightarrow\|z-x\|=\|y\|<\varepsilon\leq r_i$  
$\Rightarrow x\in B(y,r_i)$.  
I think it's not necessarily true that $B(y,r_i)\subset B(y,r_y)$, so how can we see that $x\in\Omega$?

Comment: @Pedro A ball of small radius around a given point is certainly contained in a ball of larger radius.

Comment: (There are some errors in third line of my last comment. I should have written $z$ instead of $y$.) Ok, but what are the point and the radius that you are talking about? I think you are saying that $r_i\leq r_z$, however it seems possible $B(z,r_z)$ not be in the finite subcover, so that $r_i$ can be greater than $r_z$. I think it is missing something in my reasoning or there is something wrong. Could you explain me it or complete the answer in your post?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** For each $x\in K$ there is $\varepsilon_x>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)\subset\Omega$.

Comment: Could you post details? What is the choose to $\varepsilon$?

Comment: This is the definition of openness of $\Omega$.

Comment: Ok, but how much small should $\varepsilon$ be to we get $B_\varepsilon(0)+K\subset\Omega$?